# Joining linq to Dataset Query using multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

Hi I' m trying to join 2 DataTables the left one contain 3 different column as primary key and other one the same column as foreign key here is the left Datatable Image:

[image]

and the Right DataTable Imge is this one:

[image]

here is the code I' m trying to use but is returning nothing and it supposed to

```
var query5 =
        from ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal in chanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.AsEnumerable()
        join Node in node.AsEnumerable() 
            on new { 
                 A = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<int?>("diffusers_Id"), 
                 B = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<int?>("analogs_Id"), 
                 C = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<int?>("wallstats_Id") }
            equals new { 
                 A = Node.Field<int?>("diffusers_Id"), 
                 B = Node.Field<int?>("analogs_Id"), 
                 C = Node.Field<int?>("wallstats_Id") 
            }                  
        select new
        {
            channel_Id = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<int?>("channel_Id"),
            number = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<string>("number"),
            nodeGroups_Id = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<int>("nodeGroups_Id"),
            analogNodeSerial = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<string>("analogNodeSerial"),
            diffuserNodeSerial = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<string>("diffuserNodeSerial"),
            wallStatNodeSerial = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<string>("wallStatNodeSerial"),
            diffusers_Id = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<int?>("diffusers_Id"),
            analogs_Id = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<int?>("analogs_Id"),
            wallstats_Id = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<int?>("wallstats_Id"),
            typeCode = Node.Field<string>("typeCode"),
            node_Id = Node.Field<int?>("node_Id")

        };
```

can anyone tell me why this is happening or the query I' m writing  is wrong, please can you guys help me.

Comment: What are the results? Do you get any exception here?

Comment: no I don't get any exception but it return empty dataTaable

Comment: It may be because DBNull! = null

Comment: Does the "Right DataTable" always have records with empty key values? Maybe you want them to match if there is _at least one match_? I.e. `where A == A OR B == B OR C == C`. As pointed out below, the data you show will never have a match.

Comment: Yeah I come to realise that, definitly what you are saying is what I did. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample data, you don't have any matches here (zeros do not match nulls). If this is OK due to logic of your application, then you can convert field's value to `int` instead of `Nullable<int>`. In this case default value (zero) will be provided for `DbNull` cells:

```
    on new { 
         A = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<int>("diffusers_Id"), 
         B = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<int>("analogs_Id"), 
         C = ChanToNGrsToNgrDAnWal.Field<int>("wallstats_Id") 
    }
    equals new { 
         A = Node.Field<int>("diffusers_Id"), 
         B = Node.Field<int>("analogs_Id"), 
         C = Node.Field<int>("wallstats_Id") 
    }
```

Comment: @Clement why I don't know what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: @Clement just add default values for first key selector

Comment: I tried that as well didn't work still syntax error, I was wondering if there is no other way I can use to join this DataTable?

Comment: @Clement updated answer. I think `<int>` instead of `<int?>` should do the job in your case.